# Recompiling old CLP38 program

Tags: ibm-midrange

Hey I have an Old CLP38 program that I have been updating to work in IBM I 7.4. (CLLE)

But it seems that the SAVOBJ command has been updated, with some deprecated parameters (LOC in my case). But I can't seem to find any information about it.

Currently the method is looking like this:

```
             SAVOBJ     OBJ(&NAME) LIB(&TOOBJLIB) OBJTYPE(&OBJTYPE) +
                        LOC(&SAVOPT *SEARCH)
```

But when compiling it, I get this error:
`Nøgleordet LOC er ikke gyldigt til kommandoen.` (translated to : `Keyword LOC is not valid for the command`)

Comment: did you see the available parameters to `SAVEOBJ` in the docs? (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/savobj.html)

Comment: @Luuk Yes ? But no where is it described what LOC was, so i can replace it with something new.

Comment: I am not an expert, but what happens when you leave it out ?

Comment: @Luuk I cannot just run it. It's a program that moves our files from testing environment into production environment. Which is the reason I created the question, to figure out, what it does or how it is replaced.

Comment: This [pdf (http://www.audentia-gestion.fr/IBM/PDF/sc413735.pdf) shows "The diskette LOC parameter is replaced ....."   I do not know if that's the same parameter as in you example,   If not, try: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ibm+%22CLP38%22+LOC), or a slight changed variant of this....  

Comment: Your link is weird :)

Comment: type... (sorry) it should have been: This pdf http://www.audentia-gestion.fr/IBM/PDF/sc413735.pdf shows "The diskette LOC parameter is replaced ....." I do not know if that's the same parameter as in you example, If not, try: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ibm+%22CLP38%22+LOC), or a slight changed variant of this..